# Android Mobile Server

Tags: android, sql-server, mobile

As a capstone project, my group and I are designing a couple of applications for a bus line. There will be a bus side application for the bus driver to send his location to the server, the server then sends this info to a user side app letting him know whether the bus is late or on time.

I'm handling all the server side components. I'm familiar with setting up servers on desktops, but I've yet to decide on the best approach for this since I'm a little unfamiliar with mobile application servers.

The applications are being coded with Java and using XML for parsing, so we decided on an HTTP server, but I may also code an SQL database that has a schedule of the bus arrival and departure times. I just need advice on a starting point to best approach this since all of my research hasn't given a definitive answer.

Comment: What exactly do you want? This question is vague and broad. Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: I need a way that both android applications can communicate with a lightweight server. The bus side application needs to query the server and send its GPS data at arbitrary but semi frequent intervals. The user side app then needs to query the server for the GPS info, and compare it to the scheduled time of arrival, then display whether the bus is late or on time. Since the semester has just begun I've tried modifying a little bit of sample code in a wamp server but I'm unsure of exactly what components I'll need within the code.